# Can't fadeOut parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I made a tooltip-like div where I display some messages to visitors. I also made a close button for that div. The problem is that I can't `fadeOut` the tooltip div when close button is pressed. Close button is located inside the tooltip div. I tryed with `$(this).parent().fadeOut(300);` but it's not working. If I set `hide()` instead of `fadeOut` it's working. What could be the problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="msg_1" id="msg-1">
<div class="msg_type_1"></div>
<div class="msg_text">Changes saved</div>
<div class="msg_close"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Show message
$('#msg-1').fadeIn(600).delay(4000).fadeOut(600);

// Close messages
$('.msg_close').click(function() {
$(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like because of the previous animation queue.

You have a delay of 4 seconds before `fadeOut()` is called on dom ready, but if you click before the 4 seconds are over the function will get added to the end of the animation queue thus will not get called immediately.

You can clear the existing queue with [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
// Show message
$('#msg-1').fadeIn(600).delay(4000).fadeOut(600);

// Close messages
$('.msg_close').click(function() {
$(this).parent().stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3quB2/)

Comment: Beat me to it. Bravo, bravo.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is because you have put a delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $('#msg-1').hide().fadeIn(600);
    $(".msg_close").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
    });


    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".msg_close").parent().fadeOut(600);
    },4000)


});
```